# Add items to another view controller table view on button click

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, delegates

I have a view controller called ListViewController and another called AddFoodViewController. In ListViewController users are able to add their own ingredients to the grocery list which is presented in a table view. When they go to the AddFoodViewController, users should be able to click a button which says "add to list" which will add the array of ingrediets (that are already presented in a table view) into the grocery list. I am new to this, so I was wondering if anyone can help? I have successfully been able to get the ListViewController to work, however I am not sure how to add the array of ingredients from AddFoodViewController into the previous ListViewController.

```
class AddFoodViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var FoodTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var sendFoodBtn: UIButton!

//array of food
let array = ["1 Salad", "3oz Chicken", "2 Tomatoes", "2 Cucumbers"]
let category = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}


//display array in table view
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return(array.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let foodCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "foodCell")
        foodCell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        foodCell.backgroundColor = .clear
        foodCell.textLabel?.textColor = .darkGray
        foodCell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: (foodCell.textLabel?.font.fontName)!, size:17)
        return foodCell

    }


//button that is supposed to add all ingredients to the ListViewController
 @IBAction func addOnClick(_ sender: Any) {


}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "toList"){
       let vc = (segue.destination as! ListViewController)
       vc.category = array
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: when your add button is clicked append the new data in the array and reload the tableView to show the new data

Comment: Unrelated but initializing cells in `cellForRow` is very bad practice. Design a prototype cell in Interface Builder and **reuse** it. And `return` is not a function, remove the parentheses: `return array.count`.

Comment: I am little bit confused. You say the List Then food, but I see the segue is from food to list.

Comment: @AnkurLahiry, that is what I want to do. To add the food ingredients from the array in AddFoodViewController to the grocery list (ListViewController) tableview. But I am not sure how to do this, I have tried segue but I think I am doing it wrong or do I need to use delegate because the grocery list is in a previous view controller? But I don't know exactly how to implement it.

Comment: @Wings how would you do this? I need delegate?

Comment: @Laura94...Can you be more specific what are you trying to achieve??

Answer (score 0):

Passing data to previous view controller can be implemented by delegation pattern, first at all, declare a protocol in your `AddFoodViewController`, and define a delegate property in view controller.

```
// AddFoodViewController.swift
protocol AddFoodViewControllerDelegate {
    func addIngredient(array: [String])
}

class AddFoodViewController: UIViewController {
  ...
  var delegate: AddFoodViewControllerDelegate?

  // MARK: add function
  func actionAdd() {
    delegate?addIngredient(array)
  }
  ...
}
```

Back to your `ListViewController`,find the segue destination view controller which is your `AddFoodViewController` (remember to assign its class name in the storyboard), and assign delegate to self.

```
// ListViewController.swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    ...
    let vc = segue.destination as? AddFoodViewController
    vc?.delegate = self
    ...
}

// in the same file, implement delegate method here
extension ListViewController: AddFoodViewControllerDelegate {
    func addIngredient(array: [String]) {
        items += array
        // do table reload or something
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing the code, but for some reason when I try to append the array in the extension it gives me "Use of unresolved identifier 'array' "

Comment: Need more info about your code and ListViewController code as well, and don't just copy & paste, some variable naming is not the same.

Comment: ListViewController is basically a grocery list where the user can add and delete their own grocery items: `var items: [String] = []`. The other view controller (AddFoodViewController) contains a tableview inside that displays an array of ingredients for a particular meal. So when the user presses the  "add to list" button, those ingredients for the meal automatically get added to the grocery list.

Comment: The array of ingredients in the AddFoodViewController is `var array = ["1 Salad", "3oz Chicken", "2 Tomatoes", "2 Cucumbers"]` , so I am not sure why it gives me an error when I try to append it in the ListViewController extension. Sorry I hope I am explaining this clearly and it makes sense.

Comment: View hierarchy: ListViewController -> AddFoodViewController right? `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` should be implemented in ListViewController

Comment: Yes that is how the hierarchy goes. I think that is where I implemented it though? :/

Comment: `yourArray.append(text)` should be `items.append(text)`

Comment: I tried to append items, this time it doesn't give me any errors but nothing gets added from the AddFoodViewController ingredients array. :(

Comment: I updated the code, please check to see if it is your case, add ingredients array from AddFoodVC to ListVC

Comment: Now when I do `items.append(array)` it gives me an error saying "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String' "

Comment: array add to array, just do `items += array`.

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't add anything from the AddFoodVC array to ListVC items :/

Comment: In my view hierarchy there is HomeVC, which has two images with a tap gesture on them to go to ListVC or to RecipesVC, when you click on the one labeled "Grocery List" it takes you to the ListVC, the other one takes you to RecipesVC. Inside RecipesVC there are 3 images which have a tap gesture on them. For example, the first image takes you to AddFoodVC. This is the one that I am trying to send the array from.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Swift, so I don't know if I would need to delegate through all of those VC's to get the array to the ListVC and how I would do that? Maybe this is why nothing is working?

Comment: I created a very simple delegate example project [here](https://github.com/pqteru/DelegateExample), please have a try and check is that you wanna achieve

Comment: I tried it, but it still didn't add the array. I'm not sure why :/

Comment: maybe you can upload to github too, I can examine it a bit.